# Count the number of rows per column in Bash Shell

Tags: bash, unix

I am new to Bash Shell and I could'nt find useful resources online(maybe someone can suggest some resources for me). I am working on a csv file and I would like to know how to get the count of rows per column without the nulls.

I know we use this code to count the number of lines in a file. But what if I want to specify a column?

`cat FILE_NAME  | wc -l`

For example, I have the below csv file

```
ID   Name
------------
13    Sara
22    Suzan
null  Mark
49    John
```

I would like the count for ID column to return 3.

Thank you,

Comment: You can use `awk` and increment a counter variable whenever the column doesn't contain `null`, then print the variable at the end.

Comment: As for the resources - I learned a lot by reading the whole [coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html). Be sure not to miss the chapter on [Software Tools](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Opening-the-software-toolbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on assumption of required output, you have given

```
$ cat testfile 
ID   Name
------------
13    Sara
22    Suzan
null  Mark
49    John

$ awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]*$/{ count++ }END{print count}' testfile 
3

$ awk 'function is_num(x){return(x==x+0);} is_num($1){ count++ }END{print count}' testfile 
3
```

Comment: Thank you, the first line worked just fine. I also added NR>1 to skip the header.
`awk 'NR>1 && $2 ~/[0-9]*$/  {count++ }END{print count}' testfile`

Comment: Not trying to parse columns, just hacking a one-off solution for this case, `grep -c '^[0-9]'` would do...

Answer (score 1):

In the bash world, columns are what you make them, usually via setting something named `field separator (delimiter)`. There is some mess in the ecosystem. Usually the separator is only a single character, often `<tab>` by default (`cut`, `paste`, ...). But for example `sort` and `awk` use a whole stretch of blanks as one separator, if you don't set it manually (but you can set only a single char, if you want `<tab>`, use eg `awk -F$'\t'`).

If your data looks as in your question - that is it has fixed width columns - you'd be better of with `awk`, unless there is an empty field in one of the columns (`awk '{print $1}'`). The other option for parsing a fixed width format is eg `cut -c1-4` (from each line print characters 1 to 4, which would be your ID).

Then counting the non-nulls. You want to skip header first, that is `tail -n +3` in your case, and your 'empty' field is a string match, so `grep` is advisable (`grep -v -c 'null'`).

You can test your pipeline piece by piece by deleting it from the back (and adding `head`).

```
<input tail -n +3 |
  cut -c1-4 |
  grep -v -c 'null'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` , `cut` or `awk` as suggested before.The main idea is to count the null values of the column and then subtract from the number of rows, the number of null values you count,to find out the without null values.